# how to make contact us section working in static website like sending email using javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

how to make the contact us section working in static website not server side language because i want to make it work with html, javascript like the person enters the Name, Email and Message in form and then click on send and the website owner recieve the person data to his email account, please send me the code of javascript and html that how can i do this work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're not going to get very far here just asking for code. Go ahead and check out http://forms.brace.io/. It allows forms with no backend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can not be done solely with `HTML` and `Javascript`. Sending E-mail means you have to use mail protocols which are a special kind of request that a server can make, and JS just can not do it. Ifyou really want to do it, you should look into third party e-mail programs. But i advise you, just get a server for $6 extra per year, and you get php. The php is just a few lines of code, can be done in 1. It's really easy.

Comment: This can be done solely with HTML and JS using a mailto but there are limitations. Please see the answer I posted for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with Nicky.

Nevertheless, if you still want to get form values from static HTML you could do something like this :

```
<form action="mailto:owner@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
...
</form>
```

However, it will simply open up an email client with body containing raw key=value pairs... something like

```
field1=myvalue&field2=anothervalue
```

Answer (score 1):

Without anything on your server-side, (no PHP etc.,) you're limited to using either:

1) A link with an href like "mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=something". i.e. You can do this client side with the form submit button hooked in JS to change the window.location.href to a mailto that has the email address and subject appended. You'd have to URL encode. You could possible append the body too but the entire URL would have to end up under ~2000 characters.

2) Something server-side on a third party site that your form submits to or you call, instead of something on your own server. i.e. a web service that can take a form post and email it out for you.

Pros and cons:

- 1 Con - Need a mail client on the same machine as the web browser. Some might not have.
- 1 Con - Can't readily take a rich text input from a form and submit that, but users can type rich text and attach files using a mail client.
- 1 Pro - Everything is client side.
- 1 Pro - Easiest to implement.
- 2 Pro - No mail client required. You can use an HTML form and submit that.
- 2 Pro - You can use form with multiple fields/rich text etc.
- 2 Con - Probably a paid service so extra cost.
- 2 Con - More complicated to implement.
- 2 Con - Security concerns so need to check out carefully. Can someone else use this to send email, pretending it's a client submitting a form from your web site?

Comment: This can be done solely with HTML (no JS required) using mailto as action for form. ;)
But, there are problems similar to what you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Agree could just change the form action rather than window location. Better approach so good you mentioned. However, OP posted that user will be entering email, name and message into a form, so I was assuming there is a subject too but you are correct since the OP didn't state that. If there is a subject, JavaScript code is required to change the subject part, unless we want to leave it out.

Comment: As I understood from the question, the user will be entering his own email address not the email of the website owner. So, it is just an information of the user as other fields. The website owner's email id can be hardcoded.

Comment: Yup, agreed. Was editing my own post to be clearer. I was thinking there would be a subject (chosen on a form or typed  by user) but OP didn't state that. This is why I was thinking of transforming the URI with JS, but my bad since OP didn't state that at all. Will +1 as yours is a better answer.

Comment: Well actually, for subject you can put it as a query parameter in mailto link .. something like this
`mailto:owner@example.com?subject=my_subject_goes_here`